# Store pointer value

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

As I know, when a pointer is passed into a function, it becomes merely a copy of the real pointer. Now, I want the real pointer to be changed without having to return a pointer from a function. For example:

```
int *ptr;

void allocateMemory(int *pointer)
{
     pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

allocateMemory(ptr);
```

Another thing, which is, how can I allocate memory to 2 or more dimensional arrays? Not by subscript, but by pointer arithmetic. Is this:

```
int array[2][3];
array[2][1] = 10;
```

the same as:

```
int **array;
*(*(array+2)+1) = 10
```

Also, why do I have to pass in the memory address of a pointer to a function, not the actual pointer itself. For example:

int *a;

why not:

```
allocateMemory(*a)
```

but

```
allocateMemory(a)
```

I know I always have to do this, but I really don't understand why. Please explain to me.

The last thing is, in a pointer like this:

```
int *a;
```

Is a the address of the memory containing the actual value, or the memory address of the pointer? I always think a is the memory address of the actual value it is pointing, but I am not sure about this. By the way, when printing such pointer like this:

```
printf("Is this address of integer it is pointing to?%p\n",a);
printf("Is this address of the pointer itself?%p\n",&a);
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: The second example in your second question accesses unallocated memory. Was that on purpose?

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking a hollow check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll try to tackle these one at a time:

1. > Now, I want the real pointer to be changed without having to return a pointer from a function.

   You need to use one more layer of indirection:

   ```
   int *ptr;

   void allocateMemory(int **pointer)
   {
       *pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
   }

   allocateMemory(&ptr);
   ```

   [Here is a good explanation](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) from the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).
2. > Another thing, which is, how can I allocate memory to 2 or more dimensional arrays?

   One allocation for the first dimension, and then a loop of allocations for the other dimension:

   ```
   int **x = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 2);
   for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       x[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
   ```

   Again, [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html) is link to this exact question from the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).
3. > Is this:
   >
   > ```
   > int array[2][3];
   > array[2][1] = 10;
   > ```
   >
   > the same as:
   >
   > ```
   > int **array;
   > *(*(array+2)+1) = 10
   > ```

   **ABSOLUTELY NOT.**  Pointers and arrays are different.  You can *sometimes* use them interchangeably, however.  Check out [these questions](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) from the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).
4. > Also, why do I have to pass in the memory address of a pointer to a function, not the actual pointer itself?
   >
   > why not:
   >
   > ```
   > allocateMemory(*a)
   > ```

   It's two things - C doesn't have pass-by-reference, except where you implement it yourself by passing pointers, and in this case also because `a` isn't initialized yet - if you were to dereference it, you would cause undefined behaviour.  This problem is a similar case to [this one](http://c-faq.com/malloc/malloc1.html), found in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).
5. > ```
   > int *a;
   > ```
   >
   > Is a the address of the memory containing the actual value, or the memory address of the pointer?

   That question doesn't really make sense to me, but I'll try to explain.  `a` (when correctly initialized - your example here is not) is an address (the pointer itself).  `*a` is the object being pointed to - in this case that would be an `int`.
6. > By the way, when printing such pointer like this:
   >
   > ```
   > printf("Is this address of integer it is pointing to?%p\n",a);
   > printf("Is this address of the pointer itself?%p\n",&a);
   > ```

   Correct in both cases.

Comment: @ Carl Norum - Sure. Oh, one more thing, about the 2D array thing. How can I access element in a double pointer by pointer arithmetic? So, I have to convert it back to subscripting style?

Comment: @Amumu - a "real" 2D array and a 2D array made from an array of pointers-to-pointers are different things - you need to access their elements in different ways if you want to use pointer arithmetic.  The subscript operator will work for both, though.  Why do you need to use pointer arithmetic?

Comment: I just really want to know. Yes, I did learn about how it is store in the memory. But just in theory. Now I want to access it by pointer arithmetic to apply that (and know another way to access pointer, since switching back and forth between pointer and array make the code seems inconsistent to me and less convenient to code).

Comment: @Amumu, the whole point of the subscript operator is to make that stuff easier to read.  `a[b]` in C is *literally identical* to `*(a+b)` if `a` or `b` has pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer.  (`int**`)

To answer your second question, you can use that syntax to access a location in an existing array.
However, a nested array (`int[][]`) is not the same as a pointer to a pointer (`int**`)

To answer your third question:

Writing `a` passes the value of the variable `a`, which is a memory address.
Writing `*a` passes the value *pointed to* by the variable, which is an actual value, not a memory address.

If the function takes a pointer, that means it wants an address, not a value.
Therefore, you need to pass `a`, not `*a`.
Had `a` been a pointer to a pointer (`int**`), you would pass `*a`, not `**a`.

Comment: Thanks. But is variable a the address of the pointing value OR it's the address of the pointer itself?

Comment: A pointer stores the address of a variable.  The `*` operator takes an address and returns the value at that address.  Thus, `a` is an address and `*a` is a value.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question:

you could pass a pointer's address:

```
void allocateMemory(int **pointer) {
    *pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int *ptr;
allocateMemory(&ptr);
```

or you can return a pointer value:

```
int *allocateMemory() {
    return malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int *ptr = mallocateMemory();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused about what a pointer actually is.
A pointer is just variable whose value represents an address in memory. So when we say that `int *p` is pointer to an integer, that just means `p` is a variable that holds a number that is the memory address of an `int`.
If you want a function to allocate a buffer of integers and change the value in the variable `p`, that function needs to know where in memory `p` is stored. So you have to give it a pointer to `p` (i.e., the memory address of `p`), which itself is a pointer to an integer, so what the function needs is a pointer to a pointer to an integer (i.e., a memory address where the function should store a number, which in turn is the memory address of the integers the function allocated), so

```
void allocateIntBuffer(int **pp)
{
    // by doing "*pp = whatever" you're telling the compiler to store
    // "whatever" not in the pp variable but in the memory address that
    // the pp variable is holding.
    *pp = malloc(...);
}

// call it like
int *p;
allocateIntBuffer(&p);
```

I think the key to your questions is to understand that there is nothing special about pointer variables. A pointer is a variable like any other, only that the value stored in that variable is used to represent a position in memory.

Comment: So, in a double pointer like int **b, what is *b holding? The middle pointer between its pointer and its holding value? And in the double pointer case, what is variable b holding? Memory address of the pointer of the pointer to an int or the memory address of the integer?

Comment: `int **b` would be a variable holding a memory address. If you go to that memory address (i.e., `*b`), you'll find an `int*`. An `int*` is also a memory address. If you go to that address (i.e., `*(*b)`) you'll find an `int` value.

Answer (score 0):

Note that returning a pointer or forcing the caller to move the pointer in an out of a `void *` temp variable is the **only** way you can make use of the `void *` type to allow your function to work with different pointer types. `char **`, `int **`, etc. are not convertible to `void **`. As such, I would advise against what you're trying to do, and instead use the return value for functions that need to update a pointer, unless your function by design only works with a specific type. In particular, simple `malloc` wrappers that try to change the interface to pass pointer-to-pointer types are inherently broken.