# Pointer storage in C

Tags: c

In C, a pointer contains the memory location of another variable.  Are pointer variables stored on the stack or on the heap?

Comment: Could be either.

Comment: depends on how you store the pointer^

Comment: Angus, from memory point of view a pointer is a variable like each other then it can be both stored in the heap (if allocated or global) or in the stack (if local).

Comment: ofcourse If you declare the pointer as a local variable, then it will most likely be located on the stack, but if you declare it globally, it will likely be on the heap. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660321/store-pointer-value may be helpful to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer is just a variable. Think of it as an integer that holds a memory location, so if you have:

```
int main(...) {
    char *ptr = malloc( 100 );
    ...
}
```

then `ptr` is a four- or eight-byte value on the stack that contains the memory location of a 100-byte buffer allocated from the heap. The **memory** itself is in the heap, the **pointer** is on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand. U have explained me clearly.

Answer (score 1):

It's stored somewhere!

It depends on you, how do you define the pointer.

If it is a local variable it could be on the stack, or in a register.
If you create it via malloc() it's on the heap.
Or global, if it's defined at module scope.

```
int *pInt_global;

void foo(void)
{
  int *pIntStack;

  int **ppIntHeap;

  ppIntHeap = malloc(sizeof(int *));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Heap memory is the one created with malloc, stack memory is the one you don't create with malloc (in brief, but I should talk about static memory too).

```
int a;
int* ps;
int* ph;

ps = &a;
ph = malloc(sizeof(int));
a  = 5;

if (ph != NULL) {
    *ph = 5;
}
```

Here, ps contains the address of a variable from the stack (a), and ph the address of a variable from the heap. Note that both reference the value 5, if malloc didn't fail. Also note that the memory allocate to ph should be freed at some point, but not the one from ps !

If you receive, in a function, a pointer to something, you cannot know if it references memory from the stack or from the heap.